# How heap dump collects data

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, heap-dump

I know there are numerous ways to take heap dump of a Java Process. But I would like to know how these data are collected.

In other words, what component in the JVM provides this heap data, when dump is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, a tool like "jmap" talks to components that are not part of the Java public APIs: stuff in the `sun.jvm.hotspot.*` packages.

- If "jmap" is dumping an attached JVM, it interacts with the JVM's debug agent via JVMTI.
- In other cases, "jmap" uses various classes in `sun.jvm.hotspot.*` to extract the information from the JVM processes address space or a core dump.

If you want to understand the gory details, download the OpenJDK source code (pick any version), locate the `JMap.java` file, and start reading.